# operator関数が機能しない？

Tags: c++

int main関数の部のコメント部のなのですが[暗黙的に宣言、削除された関数です]と
エラーが出てしまい修正に困っています、ヘッダー部にoperator関数を用意しているので。何が間違えなのか検討もつきません、教えてもらえますでしょうか？初学者なので解説もお願いしたいです。参考書:新版明解c++中級編 visual studio 2017

```
//////////////////////boolArray.h////boolへの明示的特殊化をしたクラス/////

#ifndef ___Class_Template_Array_Bool
#define ___Class_Template_Array_Bool
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "Array.h"

//===== 配列クラステンプレートArray（bool型への特殊化）=====//
template<> class Array<bool> {
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
    static const int CHAR_BITS = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;

    int nelem;      // bool型配列の要素数
    int velem;      // bool型配列を格納するためのBYTE型配列の要素数
    BYTE *vec;      // BYTE型先頭要素へのポインタ

    // bool型sz個の要素の格納に必要なBYTE型配列の要素数
    static int size_of(int sz) { return (sz + CHAR_BITS - 1) / CHAR_BITS; }

public:

        //=== ビットベクトル（バイト）中の１ビットへの参照を表すためのクラス ===//
        class BitOfByteRef {
            BYTE &vec;      // 参照先BYTE
            int idx;// 参照先BYTE中のビット番号

        public:

            BitOfByteRef(BYTE& r, int i) : vec(r), idx(i) { }       // コンストラクタ

            operator bool() const { return (vec >> idx) & 1U; }     // 真偽を取得

            BitOfByteRef& operator = (bool b) {// 真偽を設定
                std::cout << "BitOfByteRef operator = \n";

                if (b)
                    vec |= 1U << idx;
                else
                    vec &= ~(1U << idx);

                return *this;
            }

        };

        //----- 添字範囲エラー class -----//
        class IdxRngErr {
            const Array<bool>* ident;
            int index;
        public:
            IdxRngErr(const Array<bool>* p, int i) : ident(p), index(i) { }

            int Index() const { return index; }
        };

    //--- 明示的コンストラクタ ---//
    explicit Array(int sz, bool v = bool()) : nelem(sz), velem(size_of(sz)) {
        vec = new BYTE[velem];

        for (int i = 0; i < velem; i++) {   // 全要素を初期化
            vec[i] = v;
            std::cout << vec[i]<<'\n';//デバック
        }
    }

    //--- コピーコンストラクタ ---//
    Array(const Array& x) {
        if (&x == this) {                       // 初期化子が自分自身であれば…
            nelem = 0;
            vec = NULL;
        }
        else {
            nelem = x.nelem;                    // 要素数をxと同じにする
            velem = x.velem;                    // 要素数をxと同じにする
            vec = new BYTE[velem];              // 配列本体を確保

            for (int i = 0; i < velem; i++)     // 全要素をコピー
                vec[i] = x.vec[i];
        }
    }

    //--- デストラクタ ---//
    ~Array() { delete[] vec; }

    //--- 要素数を返す ---//
    int size() const { return nelem; }

    //--- 代入演算子= ---//
    Array& operator = (const Array<bool>& x) {
        //std::cout << "=\n";
        if (&x != this) {                   // 代入元が自分自身でなければ…
            if (velem != x.velem) {         // 代入前後の要素数が異なれば…
                delete[] vec;               // もともと確保していた領域を解放
                velem = x.velem;            // 新しい要素数
                vec = new BYTE[velem];      // 新たに領域を確保
            }

            nelem = x.nelem;                // 新しい要素数

            for (int i = 0; i < velem; i++) // 全要素をコピー
                vec[i] = x.vec[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    //--- 添字演算子[] ---//
    BitOfByteRef operator[](int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= nelem)
            throw IdxRngErr(this, i);               // 添字範囲エラー送出

        return BitOfByteRef(vec[i / CHAR_BITS], (i & (CHAR_BITS - 1)));
    }

    //--- 添字演算子[] ---//
    bool operator[](int i) const {
        if (i < 0 || i >= nelem)
            throw IdxRngErr(this, i);               // 添字範囲エラー送出

        return (vec[i / CHAR_BITS] >> (i & (CHAR_BITS - 1)) & 1U) == 1;
    }

};

//--- Array<bool>型配列aの全要素を0または1で連続表示 ---//
void print_Array_bool(const Array<bool>& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << (a[i] ? '1' : '0');

}

#endif

/////////////////////int main関数部//////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include "BoolArray.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Array<bool> x(10);      // 全要素をfalseで初期化
    Array<bool> y(x);       // yはxのコピー（要素数が10で全要素がfalse）
    Array<bool> z(5);       // zの要素数は5だが
    z = y;                  // yが代入されるので要素数は10となる

//  z[1] = y[3];///ここです。
    y[2] = true;
    z[3] = true;

    Array<bool> a(10);

    cout << boolalpha;

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << x[i] << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "y[" << i << "] = " << y[i] << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "z[" << i << "] = " << z[i] << '\n';
        }

    }
    catch (Array<bool>::IdxRngErr &x) {
        cout << "添え字範囲エラー:";

        cout << x.Index();

        _getch();
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "x = ";  print_Array_bool(x);  cout << '\n';
    cout << "y = ";  print_Array_bool(y);  cout << '\n';
    cout << "z = ";  print_Array_bool(z);  cout << '\n';

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

直接の原因は、`Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef`型(以降、単に`BitOfByteRef`)が参照フィールド(`BYTE & vec`)を持っているため、暗黙に定義される`operator=(const BitOfByteRef &)`メソッドが定義されないことが原因と思います。

ですので、`operator=(const BitOfByteRef &)を明示的に定義することでエラーが解消されると思います。

```
        // コード例
        BitOfByteRef & operator=(const BitOfByteRef & rhs) {
            return this->operator=(rhs.operator bool());
            // 多分、これでもOK.
            // return *this = static_cast<bool>(rhs);
        }
```

---

補足です。順を追ってみてみると、

```
z[3] = y[1];
```

では、`z[3]`は`BitOfByteRef`型と評価されます。また、`y[1]`も`BitOfByteRef`型と評価されます。つまり、`BitOfByteRef`型同士の代入と見なされます。
ここで、`BitOfByteRef`型は`operator=(const BitOfByteRef &)`(代入演算子)のメンバメソッドを定義していないので、暗黙に定義されようとします。が、暗黙に定義されるメソッドでは、各メンバをコピーする処理にしようとするのですが、参照型変数自身は代入できないため、暗黙のメソッド定義は行わない(定義を禁止(`delete`))ようです。
そのため、コンパイラは「暗黙的に宣言、削除された関数です」とエラーにしていると思います。

＃`std::vector`の`std::vector<bool>`特殊化でも同じように`std::vector<bool>::reference`の代入演算子を2種類(`bool`と`reference`)定義しているようです。

Comment: 本質的な所ではありませんが、コード例の`lhs`は`rhs`（右辺）の誤りなのでは？

Comment: alpha さんのコメントのとおり変数名は誤りでした。誤解を招かないよう回答のコード例、訂正しました。

Answer (score 1):

`template <typename T> class Array;` を補って gcc-7.3.0@x86_64-cygwin で試したところ

> ```
> depr.cpp:17:13: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef' and 'Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef')
>    z[1] = y[3];///ここです。
> BoolArray.h:35:19: note: candidate: Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef& Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef::operator=(bool)
> BoolArray.h:24:9: note: candidate: Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef& Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef::operator=(const Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef&) <deleted>
> BoolArray.h:24:9: note: candidate: Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef& Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef::operator=(Array<bool>::BitOfByteRef&&) <deleted>
> ```

となりました。

で。エラーになっている原因は

- コピーコンストラクタがコンパイラによって暗黙に作られる場合がある
- `operator=` がコンパイラによって暗黙に作られる場合がある
- ところがこの例では `BitOfByteRef::operator=` を明示しているので「作られない = deleted 」
- 自前で作った `BitOfByteRef::operator=` が正しく呼べない
  （暗黙に作られるはずの `operator=` と曖昧になっている）

曖昧さがある以前に現コードはほとんど全く意味が無いです。現コードにおいて `z[1]` は `BitOfByteRef operator[] (int i) { ... }` を呼び出しています。この返却値はコピーされた `BitOfByteRef` 一時オブジェクト、つまり右辺値になっています。この右辺値に対して `operator=` を呼ぼうとしていますが、一時オブジェクト（右辺値）に代入しても意味がないです（即時デストラクトされるため）

この `z[1]=y[3];` で何がしたいのか次第で直し方が違うわけですが、どうしたいですか？

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 コンソールプロジェクト on Win10
では、コンパイルも実行もできました。
ただし、

・「Array.h」が見つからなかったので、当該インクルードをコメント化、
　かつ、以下のコード様にclass Array を自前で用意しました。

```
　template< typename T> class    Array {};
```

以上から推測するに、Array.h に問題があるのかもしれません。
「#include "Array.h"」行を右クリックしてファイルを開き、意図したものか調べてみてはどうでしょう。